# Ruby Timeout.timeout does not timeout in x secs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Below code

```
Timeout.timeout(2) do
  i = 0
  while(true)
    i = i + 1
    p "test #{i}"
  end
end
```

does not timeout in 2 secs. whereas below similar code timeout in 2 seconds

```
Timeout.timeout(2) do
  i = 0
  while(true)
    i = i + 1
    # p "test #{i}"
  end
end
```

What is the underlying difference? Please help.

Comment: Seems to be a Ruby 2.x issue. The code works just fine in in both, Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 3. (i.e. it _does_ terminate after ~2s)

Comment: Apart from the issue, `Timeout::timeout` is kind of dangerous because it will interrupt your code at an arbitrary point, possibly leaving your system in an undefined or vulnerable state. Better use some kind of timer e.g. a `run = true` flag along with `Thread.start { sleep(2) ; run = false }` and a simple `while(run)` loop. This way, it's guaranteed to finish after completing a full loop cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what's going on here and I suspect somebody who understands the underlying C code would be the one to give a complete answer. I have an inkling. The Matz Ruby Interpreter (MRI) has a global thread lock which means only one thread can actually run at any given time. The way threading works is when one thread is waiting on a resource it sleeps and this gives another thread opportunity to run.

Timeout creates a second thread that will sleep for 2 seconds then raise an exception on the current thread enforcing the timeout. We are guaranteed this thread will not run before 2 seconds but not guaranteed exactly when it will run after 2 seconds but usually a few milliseconds or so with some exceptions.

The function `p` is unique in that it writes directly to std.out. This is where a C programmer may be helpful but it appears to me that its starving the other thread of resources possibly because to throw an exception the second thread needs to own std.out.

`p` and `pp` both cause this problem whereas `puts` does not.

In support of the resource starvation theory the following code works

```
Timeout.timeout(2) do
  i = 0
  while(true)
    i = i + 1
    p "testing timeout #{i}"
    sleep 0.001
  end
end
```

Comment: As a curious note: `ruby timeout_test.rb > out` does time out even without the `sleep`.